# three.js and Angular - function is not defined

Tags: angular, three.js, frontend, angular-components

I have developed a simple application that renders a cube with Angular 4 and `three.js`. I have an Angular component called `ViewerComponent`, where the cube is rendered. The code of this component relevant to my question is the following (the code of the `init` method is not included here for simplicity):

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as THREE from 'three';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'viewer.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['viewer.component.css'],
})

export class ViewerComponent implements AfterViewInit{

    constructor() { }

    ngAfterViewInit(){
        this.init();
    }

    init(){
        // define camera, scene, cube, renderer, etc
    }

    Callback_Method(){
        console.log("RESIZE!");
    }

    onWindowResize(){   
        this.Callback_Method();
    }

}
```

I would like a message to be shown in the browser console when the size of the window of the browser is changed. Trying to implement this functionality, I found the following error.

When I run my application, and change the size of the window of the browser, the following error is raised: `ERROR TypeError: this.Callback_Method is not a function`. However, if I change the code of the method `onWindowResize` to the following, I get the expected behaviour:

```
onWindowResize(){   
    console.log("RESIZE!");
}
```

I am very new to frontend technologies and `three.js`, and now I am completely lost. Does anyone have any ideas on why could this be hapenning? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HostListener to get DOM events

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

export class ViewerComponent implements AfterViewInit{

  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
    onResize(event: Event) {
      this.Callback_Method();
    }

  constructor() { }

  Callback_Method(){
    console.log("RESIZE!");
  }
}
```

Comment: This works like a charm, thank you so much! Only one thing: I should define the type of the argument `event` in the definition of the `onResize` method, as I am using Typescript. I cannot edit your answer as it is a very small change. Could you do it for me? Thanks again.